# timestamp, datetime as default value as current_timestamp [PARTITION]

Tags: mysql

I have a table column called **`recorddate`** where it has timestamp datatype to default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Now I have few questions regarding maintenance part.

1. I should partition this table keeping `recorddate` as `rangekey`. But now it wouldn't allow partition key for timezone-dependent expressions in (sub)partitioning function.
2. If I change the *timestamp* datatype to *datetime* for `recorddate` the partition is created but it won't allow default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` database level.

   2.1 . When I see forums stating **MySQL 5.6.5** has *datetime* datatype can have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `now()`. Would it allow `rangebykey` for partition ?

[Another thought that clings on my head is, would it be good to pick a distribution that is still under developement]

Any suggestions or work around, I really don't like the concept of triggers having to be on `recordate` upon insert if null. As it seeds records almost *5 hundered thousands per day* and peak time goes to 8 transactions per second on that table. That is the intent of falling on to partitions.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? :)

Comment: timestamp doesn't work whereas datetime datatype with default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WORKS!! Any workaround if I can still stay in 5.5? And just add a plugin for this functionality?